# animation class in ng expression is not working ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, animation

I am new in ionic - angular world.
I am trying to put an animation class for my item but based on an expression the class is change. i.e odd item want to animate to left , even animate  to right.

```
  <ion-item class="{{'list_item slideInLeft'}}"
```

is not working, but

```
  <ion-item class="list_item slideInLeft"
```

animation works

I need the class in '' to work in order to be able to put is in expression:

```
class="{{i%2==0 ? 'list_item slideInLeft':'list_item slide-in-both-ways'}}"
```

I also tried:

```
ng-class-odd="'list_item slideInLeft'" ng-class-even="'list_item slideInLeft'"
```

and

```
ng-class ="{ odd: 'list_item slideInLeft', even:'list_item slideInLeft'}"
```

with no luck .

anybody has an idea, appreciated!

ionic info (if needed)

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

Node       : v6.10.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng class like below....i am just using my classes with colors so that you have to replace with your fields and values

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.name=[];
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $scope.name.push(i);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.red{
  color:red;
}
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="i in name track by $index" ng-class={red:$index%2==0,blue:$index%2!==0}>{{i}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: my expression is working well .. but the animation happening.
i.e it evaluate correctly and give the correct associated class, but it is an animation and i don't see it animated. but if i put the animation  class directly without having expression, animation works!